# Substring between two strings?

Tags: javascript

```
var str = "https://cdn.fbsbx.com/v/t59.2708-21/68856895_411975049700005_8580443955521388544_n.xls/test.xls?_nc_cat=106&_nc_oc=AQmcm2PVCUFFyUJDJgLs3ZYM4Dg12PX1Wv48Fm0LJ8-Qi8duxOpEVrD2uFgrD9e1pDOXcLpJmbtjbveAm12xczd2&_nc_ht=cdn.fbsbx.com&oh=18eab18ae1d1cf2a95084bba0a002163&oe=5D8F8124";
var n = str.substring(str.indexOf("\\.") +1 , str.indexOf("?_nc_cat="));
```

I have this string but my output is :

`https://cdn.fbsbx.com/v/t59.2708-21/68856895_411975049700005_8580443955521388544_n.xls/test.xls`

How can i get only this .xls?

My other string is :

`https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/70629455_2730574856953299_3640328874664919040_n.png?_nc_cat=100&_nc_oc=AQm0m5jryh7zAzyj2R-w7ke0DKQgHM7aYaVkkRjPYDUQ6g-FUAWqVwhnr7qxqISkWMdiNhtp7e8gYMA6gss58poN&_nc_ad=z-m&_nc_cid=0&_nc_zor=9&_nc_ht=scontent.xx&oh=1cbb98fb9484bd3f26b6058808cca889&oe=5E36459B`

but again im not getting just word "png" im getting from start link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a regular expression, and match word characters while looking ahead for  `?`:

```js
const getFileType = str => str.match(/\w+(?=\?)/)[0];

console.log(getFileType("https://cdn.fbsbx.com/v/t59.2708-21/68856895_411975049700005_8580443955521388544_n.xls/test.xls?_nc_cat=106&_nc_oc=AQmcm2PVCUFFyUJDJgLs3ZYM4Dg12PX1Wv48Fm0LJ8-Qi8duxOpEVrD2uFgrD9e1pDOXcLpJmbtjbveAm12xczd2&_nc_ht=cdn.fbsbx.com&oh=18eab18ae1d1cf2a95084bba0a002163&oe=5D8F8124"));

console.log(getFileType('https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/70629455_2730574856953299_3640328874664919040_n.png?_nc_cat=100&_nc_oc=AQm0m5jryh7zAzyj2R-w7ke0DKQgHM7aYaVkkRjPYDUQ6g-FUAWqVwhnr7qxqISkWMdiNhtp7e8gYMA6gss58poN&_nc_ad=z-m&_nc_cid=0&_nc_zor=9&_nc_ht=scontent.xx&oh=1cbb98fb9484bd3f26b6058808cca889&oe=5E36459B'));
```

Comment: why lookahead `str.match(/\.(\w+)\?/)[1]` ?

Comment: Sure, you could do something like that too, but it's a bit more complicated and doesn't change the output

Answer (score 0):

**Simply**, Just you have to use the `LastIndexof()` in the right way to achieve this

```
str = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/70629455_2730574856953299_3640328874664919040_n.png?_nc_cat=100&_nc_oc=AQm0m5jryh7zAzyj2R-w7ke0DKQgHM7aYaVkkRjPYDUQ6g-FUAWqVwhnr7qxqISkWMdiNhtp7e8gYMA6gss58poN&_nc_ad=z-m&_nc_cid=0&_nc_zor=9&_nc_ht=scontent.xx&oh=1cbb98fb9484bd3f26b6058808cca889&oe=5E36459B";
url = str.substring(0,str.indexOf("?"));
ext = str.substring(url.lastIndexOf(".")+1, url.length);
```

The same will work for any other string as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you're trying to get the last value from `pathname` which is preceded by `.` from URL, so you can use [`URL API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

Simply parse the URL with URL api, take the patname value and split on `.` and take the last element from splitted array.

```js
var str = "https://cdn.fbsbx.com/v/t59.2708-21/68856895_411975049700005_8580443955521388544_n.xls/test.xls?_nc_cat=106&_nc_oc=AQmcm2PVCUFFyUJDJgLs3ZYM4Dg12PX1Wv48Fm0LJ8-Qi8duxOpEVrD2uFgrD9e1pDOXcLpJmbtjbveAm12xczd2&_nc_ht=cdn.fbsbx.com&oh=18eab18ae1d1cf2a95084bba0a002163&oe=5D8F8124";

let valueExtractor = (str) =>{
  let urlParse = new URL(str)
  return urlParse.pathname.split('.').pop()
}


console.log(valueExtractor(str))
console.log(valueExtractor("https://cdn.fbsbx.com/v/t59.2708-21/68856895_411975049700005_8580443955521388544_n.xls/test.png?_nc_cat=106&_nc_oc=AQmcm2PVCUFFyUJDJgLs3ZYM4Dg12PX1Wv48Fm0LJ8-Qi8duxOpEVrD2uFgrD9e1pDOXcLpJmbtjbveAm12xczd2&_nc_ht=cdn.fbsbx.com&oh=18eab18ae1d1cf2a95084bba0a002163&oe=5D8F8124"))
```